# Why is this Postgis distance query so slow? Postgres' query estimator off by a factor of 10000x?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgis

I'm trying to find all posts that were within a certain distance, but unfortunately for some inputs the query is extremely slow. Here's some examples:

```
-- fast (1 millisecond)
SELECT 1
FROM post po
WHERE ST_DWithin(po.geog, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-47, -70), 4326)::geography, 4500 * 1609.34)
LIMIT 10;

-- slow (2 seconds)
SELECT 1
FROM post po
WHERE (po.geog <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-47, -70), 4326)::geography) < 4500 * 1609.34
LIMIT 10;

-- slow (9 seconds)
SELECT 1
FROM post po
WHERE ST_DWithin(po.geog, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-70, 40), 4326)::geography, 4500 * 1609.34)
ORDER BY po.reply_count DESC, convo_id DESC
LIMIT 10;

-- fast (1 millisecond)
SELECT 1
FROM post po
WHERE (po.geog <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-70, 40), 4326)::geography) < 4500 * 1609.34
ORDER BY po.reply_count DESC, convo_id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Here is the visualization of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the third query that is taking 9 seconds: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Xd6d

Here is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the fourth query: https://explain.depesz.com/s/zcKa

Basically, depending on the inputs, it seems like the non-indexed distance using the `<->` is sometimes faster, and then for other inputs, the indexed distance operator (`ST_DWithin`) is faster.

I think that `ST_DWithin` *should* basically always be faster (or at least complete in a reasonable amount of time), but for some reason in this case it is having an incredible runtime. Does anyone know why the query planner is so off? Based on the explain output, it looks like Postgres thinks there's going to be 100 rows, but there are actually 1,000,000 rows.

Here are the relevant indexes that I have:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX post_pk ON public.post USING btree (convo_id)
CREATE INDEX post_geog_spidx ON public.post USING spgist (geog)
CREATE INDEX post_reply_count_convo_id_idx ON public.post USING btree (reply_count, convo_id)
CREATE INDEX post_reply_count_idx ON public.post USING btree (reply_count)
```

Using a `gist` instead of a `spgist` for `geog` did not affect the runtime.

All my geographies are points and I have run `VACUUM (ANALYSE, VERBOSE);` already

My version numbers are:

`PostgreSQL 12.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

and

`POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY`

Comment: Indexes would be good to show also, without them hard to say what the index is for even or what type

Comment: Ah good call I'll add them now.

Comment: We would need to see the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for the 4th query as well, so we can compare it to the 3rd.

Comment: @jjanes I've edited the post with the EXPLAIN for the 4th query

Comment: "I think that ST_DWithin should basically always be faster (or at least complete in a reasonable amount of time),"  Considering that over a million rows seem to satisfy the ST_DWithin, that is not a very reasonable expectation.

Comment: Shouldn't that run instantly though? If every row satisfies the geog condition then just do the indexed ORDER BY and grab the first 10 rows?

Comment: "If every row satisfies the geog condition"  It has no way of knowing that ahead of time.  The planner can't use information it doesn't have.

Comment: I think I'm right in stating the spgist index has no effect unless it is in order by clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimating the number of rows which will be returned by these types of multidimensional operations is very hard.  It would require types of statistics which PostgreSQL doesn't gather.

So it is mostly upon you to figure out how many rows will qualify (before the LIMIT), and craft your query appropriately.  Is your ST_DWithin always so unrestrictive?  Do you know ahead of time when it is going to be so unrestrictive?

I'm not a GIS expert, <s>but I think the units for SRID 4326 is degrees, so pretty much everything is going to be within (4500 * 1609.34) degrees of everything else, isn't it?</s>

Comment: It's not always so restrictive. The user can choose the miles distance amount (anywhere between 1 miles away to 15,000 miles away). It just fails on the large range. Is the solution to basically only use the index when there's a small number of expected rows? Seems to defeat the point of an index?

Comment: He's using geography so his units are in meters, NOT degrees.  Well so I am assuming, his structure looks like this - CREATE TABLE post(convo_id bigint, reply_count bigint, geog geography);

Comment: @RyanPeschel When the number of miles is small, the index will work well.  That is its purpose.  It would be nice if it automatically detected when the number of miles is too large for it to work well, but failing that at least you should have the ability to peek at the miles and switch queries before submitting.

Comment: So basically I should do some sort of `CASE` statement with the input miles amount? Use `ST_DWithin` when the miles amount is below some arbitrary number (like 75), and then use the non-indexed one above that?

Comment: I don't think the CASE would work.  I think you need to make the decision in the app server, before submitting to the database.  They might have better ideas for you over at https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That is extremely unfortunate then. I would basically need to have two versions of the stored procedure that differ only in this one aspect. If only there was a way to inform Postgres not to use the index if the input area was too large..

Comment: If you are using stored functions (other than those implemented in LANGUAGE SQL), you can implement the decision there.  It wouldn't be in a CASE, but rather an IF (or whatever the equivalent would be in your favorite pl language).

Comment: I'll have to research that then. I've only ever used `LANGUAGE SQL`. Not sure if you're familiar with it and would want to post that as an answer.

Comment: Might be best to ask that as a different question, showing the current definition of your SQL function.

Comment: @jjanes Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472350/how-to-switch-between-an-indexed-and-non-indexed-operation-depending-on-the-inpu

Answer (score 0):

For this one the distance operator only uses an index when in the ORDER BY close,

```
SELECT 1
FROM post po
 WHERE (po.geog <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-47, -70), 4326)::geography) < 4500 * 1609.34
LIMIT 10;
```

so try doing this instead:

```
WITH d AS (SELECT (po.geog <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-47, -70), 4326)::geography) AS dist
FROM post po
 ORDER BY dist
LIMIT 10) 
SELECT * FROM d WHERE d.dist < (4500 * 1609.34);
```

Comment: That latter query unfortunately takes 12 seconds to complete for me.

Comment: Does it use an index?

Comment: Here's the explain output for it: https://explain.depesz.com/s/lmqH